# Github でのプルリクエストのマージ待ちの際の良い運用について

Tags: git, github

Git でブランチAを作り、プルリエクストを送ったとします。
ブランチA がマージ待ちの状態で、Aをベースに新たにブランチBを切って機能を付け加えたい場合、どのような運用がベターでしょうか。

- AをベースにブランチBを作成して開発、プルリクエストを送る(BのプルリクにはAのコミット履歴も乗ってしまうが、masterとのマージ作業を省略できる)
- master から B を作成して開発、Aが master にマージされた後、 origin/master を B にマージしてプルリクエストを送る

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AをベースにブランチBを作成して開発、プルリクエストを送る(BのプルリクにはAのコミット履歴も乗ってしまうが、masterとのマージ作業を省略できる)

自分はこの方法に近い形で運用しています。
ただし、Aがmasterにマージされるまでは、Bのプルリクはしないようにしています（上記のようにAのコミットが混入するため）
できればBはpushもしない方がいいです。そしてAがmasterにマージされたら、Bをrebaseしてから、pushとプルリクをしています。こうすると樹形図もシンプルになります。

この方法を使えば、Aがプルリク待ちでもAのコードをベースに開発の続きをすることができると思います。
まぁ、なるべくプルリク待ちで作業がストップしないような開発体制にすることも大切ですね

Answer (score 0):

ブランチAに依存した機能をつかってブランチBを作りたい、ということですね。
後者＋A->Bへのマージを入れると良いと思います。

> master から B を作成して開発、Aが master にマージされた後、 origin/master を B にマージしてプルリクエストを送る

ブランチからブランチを作ると樹形図が複雑になってしまうので、プルリクを処理する人が追いかける人の負担となる場合が多いです。
ただこのやり方でも樹形図が回り込むような形になってしまいます。

Gitの運用ですと幾つかのモデルケース(開発フロー）があるのでそちらを使ってみてアレンジしていく、という方法がお勧めです。（すでにご存知でしたらすみません。

- git-flow
- GitHub flow
- Hg flow

ご参考までに。

Comment: git-flowとPRは共存できなくはないですが、git-flowの強み()の半分以上は使えないフローになりますね。PRが本家でマージされた後、手元のfeatureブランチはどうしますか？手動削除？

Comment: 手元は手動削除、remoteはマージした人かPR作った人、管理者的な人が削除してますね。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！するとA の機能がないと作れないような B を作る場合は、マージを待つしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 言葉足らずで認識を間違えてました。うちの場合ですと
1. AからmasterへのPR
1. masterからブランチBを作成
1. ブランチAからブランチBへマージ
を行っています。